# Check if Sentry report modal is already open to prevent multiple popups

Tags: javascript, angular, sentry

I'm using Sentry to catch errors and when error is thrown, Sentry report modal is shown. However if multiple errors are thrown, user gets e.g. 10 report modals and has to close them all to get back to the program.

Bellow I have my code where I check if the error is the same - in this case if error is the same and modal was already shown, second modal will not be shown.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor() {
    }

    errors: string[] = [];

    handleError(error) {
        if (environment.production) {
            const capturedError = error.originalError || error;
            const eventId = Sentry.captureException(capturedError);
            if (!this.errors.includes(capturedError.toString())) {
                Sentry.showReportDialog({
                    eventId: eventId,
                });
            }

            this.errors.push(capturedError.toString());
        }
    }
```

However there might be case when errorA and errorB, ..., happens at the same time. In that case sentry would still show multiple modals at once. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can show only the last dialog using this method.

**Throttle the dialogs to only show the last using a timeout:**

```js
//error-handler.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {
  }

  errors: string[] = [];
  timer: any;

  handleError(error) {
    if (environment.production) {
      const capturedError = error.originalError || error;
      const eventId = Sentry.captureException(capturedError);
      if (!this.errors.includes(capturedError.toString())) {

        // Clear existing timeout so that its does not fire and open a dialog
        if (this.timer) {
          clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }

        // Register a new timeout to open the dialog in 500ms
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          Sentry.showReportDialog({
            eventId: eventId,
          });
        }, 500);
      }

      this.errors.push(capturedError.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Really you don't need to even have a separate `ErrorHandler` in this case though, Sentry provides the `beforeSend` option to run code just before an error is sent and you can put your timeout in there. Assuming you are running this in Angular, it would look like this:

```js
//main.ts

let dialogShownTimeout: any;

Sentry.init({
  //...
  environment: environment.production ? "prod" : "dev",
  dsn: environment.sentry.key,
  beforeSend(event, hint) {
    // Check if it is an exception, and if so, show the report dialog
    if (event.exception) {
      // Timeout ensures only the lasty dialog is sent if multiple errors are received
      if (dialogShownTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(dialogShownTimeout);
      }
      dialogShownTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        Sentry.showReportDialog({ eventId: event.event_id });
      }, 250);
    }
    return event;
  }

});
//...
```